# Need USB drivers for Nexus One and Mac Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac, android

I got a AT&T compatible Nexus One that I'm trying to connect to my Mac Book Pro (Snow Leopard) for development.  When I do an **adb devices**, it doesn't appear, and I can't do an **adb install** either.  Until today, I've been using a G1 and I haven't had any issues.  I haven't placed a SIM in the phone yet, but I don't think that should matter.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh.  Forgot to turn on USB debugging on the phone itself.  It is documented.  I didn't have to do this on first phone that I borrowed because it was already done.

http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/developing/device.html

"Turn on "USB Debugging" on your device.
On the device, go to the home screen, press MENU, select Applications > Development, then enable USB debugging."